# Problem getting jQuery offset() to work on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, offset

In my code, `offset()` always returns 0,0 for elements loaded from ajax or `load()` method - any ideas?

Contrived sample code:

```
jQuery("#div1").load(url, function() {
   var offset = jQuery("#some-div-in-new-content").offset();
   // offset is always 0,0
});
```

I have validated that `jQuery("#some-div-in-new-content")` is finding the object - other properties are good.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or jsbin example?

Comment: May be you should try getting `offset()` outside the `load` function

Comment: @TheSuperTramp: Whilst I would also recommend trying this, the docs say that the callback should fire after the HTML insertion. The DOM *should* be ready by this point.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal so the problem must be something else.. not because the stuff is ajax loaded..

Comment: @TheSuperTramp: Yea, I can't quite figure this one out :/

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, of course, [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) *does* work with ajax-loaded content: https://output.jsbin.com/gixoxojomu. It would be very, very, *very* strange if it didn't, since there's basically no way to tell, once new content has been loaded into the DOM, where it came from.

So the question has to be, why isn't it working on your page? We can't answer that for sure from the given information, but here are some possible reasons:

- Perhaps you have a *different* div with the ID `some-div-in-new-content`, somewhere else on the page, that has the 0,0 offset.
- Perhaps the content is hidden. From the documentation:

  > jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem and checking the position of the newly loaded elements with `offset().top` revealed that my problem was with not using `clear: both;` after the element.
Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Loaded HTML's parent was hidden and so offset were zero. So make sure after loading HTML response make it or its parent visible and then calculate offset.